# What is the best webinterface to manage BIND?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I set up BIND DNS which hosts our domain, and I also use it for internal DNS. I set up different views for internal and external hosts and it works OK.
My question is which is the best webinterface to manage the BIND server, which will allow me to use views in the named.config ?
I have tried MyDNS, SMBIND and ProBIND but none seems to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What exactly is what you want?

Comment: I want to be able to edit zone files and also be able to use the "view" clause in order to serve different records for different hosts.

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow Convict's advice and try getting into manually editing the files. I run approximately 1400 domains using vi and a little scripting. Setup rndc correctly and a change/reload literally takes less than a minute.
Check out the O'Reilly DNS & Bind book....

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an entire list of web frontend GUI's for BIND.

Without knowing exactly what you want, I cannot recommend one specifically.

[BIND GUI's](http://www.debianadmin.com/bind-dns-server-web-interfacefrontend-or-gui-tools.html)

Comment: from this list only Webmin has the functionality that I needed.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

vi.  emacs.  Your favourite text editor.  :-)

You'd be better off learning how to edit the configuration files directly rather than relying on some incomplete GUI tool.  You have complete control when you use your favourite text editor.

Comment: +1. They're just text files, and knowing them is essential to knowing BIND.

Answer (score 2):

Bind doesn't have any particular web interface. Use [PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com/) instead.

Comment: +1 for powerdns. everybody should be dropping BIND it's a piece of software that I just don't get why everybody keeps using it when there are better alternatives.

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist responding to this. While PowerDNS is fine software, even now in 2014 it still does not provide many of the features that ISC BIND does provide. Sure, it's alright to have a personal preference towards PDNS, but labelling it as a "better alternative" to BIND might cause clue seekers to be disappointed later on, when the feature they require is unsupported, undocumented or even unwanted in PDNS.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new app now that supports views configuration via a webUI called fmDNS which should do what you are looking for.  It's a part of a suite of apps - http://www.facilemanager.com/modules/fmdns/

Answer (score 1):

If you actually understand DNS and the terminology, the administrative interface in Webmin is effective for making quick simple changes to zones.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until the release of Bind10, it will be easy to build web interfaces 'cause bind10 support sql. until this time use webmin for that or your favorite editor. It is not difficult to set zones, domain with Bind it syntax is so simple.