# Sell a subdomain like a real domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I own a domain name called "ygn.cc" just like co.cc or com.us. What I would like to do is to sell yourname.ygn.cc really cheap but just like the real domain features such as editing records. I have a Linux Cpanel/WHM server with name servers to handle that, but I'm not sure where to start.

I need to automate registrations of new subdomains
I need to allow users to change records such as "A Record" and "CNAME"

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This is a multi-pronged question. It may not seem like it, but what you're asking for is really quite complicated.

You need a system to:

1. Handle purchases and credit card transactions
2. Handle renewals of intervals on your chosen timeline
3. A web-interface to your DNS nameservers so the user can manipulate their own records

and, most importantly, you need a *really, really* good lawyer to do you an iron-clad terms of service when you're purchasing, because nomatter what you say, YOU still own the primary domain, which means that YOU still own the subdomains.

For example, what happens if you forget to renew your domain? All your subdomain users will be left out in the cold and they'll want their money back, and possibly even compensation.

You will also want to read the terms of service for the purchase of your domain to make sure that this is even legal under the terms of the TLD (`.cc`)

None of these issues really fall under a typical "server administrator" role, it's more of a business logic/programmer role.

The only part of your question that is appropriate for here is "How can my customers manage the DNS via a web interface", in which case [there is an appropriate question that has already been asked for that here](https://serverfault.com/questions/10686/what-is-the-best-webinterface-to-manage-bind).

Comment: Also, what happens when one of your users has child porn on <strike>their</strike>.... sorry, *your* subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide different types of services:

Easiest would be just allow to delegate domain to own nameservers, then you will be adding `IN NS` records for user subdomains and that's it.

For more complex solutions you should allow to:

1. Set A/CNAME for subdomain,
2. Set multiple MX records for subdomain (like redirect to gmail mail exchangers) (check this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=7273f9a54a918139&hl=en),
3. Set TXT records (for spf),
4. add subdomains to user subdomain