# Easier than bind dns for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dns-server

I'm looking for a simple to use DNS server for my network,

I wanna be able to define a set of domains and point them to different IPS within the network.

What is an easy solution I could use, I found bind to be too complicated

Comment: BIND complicated? in that case you may be better off asking about a front end, rather than a different DNS server.

Comment: What exactly about BIND do you find complicated? Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS server is fairly pointy clicky.

Comment: Good point, is there a good frontend for bind? preferably web based

Comment: Now we're a dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/10686/what-is-the-best-webinterface-to-manage-bind

Comment: Well bind has really complicated config files, I wanna do something simple I need to be able to add domain name and IP address as A records I don't wanna have to read a lot of manuals for that

Comment: You want to be able to use server software without ever reading the manual? There's no life power-up for that.

Comment: Please don't be too analytical, you know what I mean, I'm looking for a good recommendation

Comment: If reading the manual seems like too much effort for you, people generally aren't going to put a lot of time into helping you out. This is a community of people who are genuinely happy to put in time helping people out who need it, not just those who are lazy. If you want DNS server recommendations, I've seen BIND, PowerDNS, DJBDNS (less so) and Windows Server DNS all deployed and used. And yes, they all come with manuals. Windows is the most pointy-clicky, like I already said.

Comment: webmin understands the bind config files and is probably the easiest to get up and running.

Comment: Tom H, who cares? I'm not interested in becoming a "webmin" I need something up and running quickly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to serve authoratative zones to the Internet?  Or is this only for your internal network?  DNSMasq is pretty easy and flexible for a small internal network.

Comment: It is for the internal network as stated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

For people who want to reap the benefits of name based services on a network, but don't care to set up the infrastructural needs to support this, because they do not want to learn or read manuals, I generally recommend [the hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

That being said, those are typically the same people I recommend a new line of work.

If your question is really serious, and you want an easy-to-manage DNS server, follow [@growse](https://serverfault.com/users/68794/)'s suggestion and install a [Microsoft DNS server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725925.aspx), preferably on either Windows Server 2003 or 2008 R2.

You will, however, need to read the documentation provided

Comment: I strongly object to the idea that a hosts file is ever a vlid answer.

Comment: @Zoredache agreed, it's an alternative (and an almost useless one at that)

Comment: +1 for "those are typically the same people I recommend a new line of work".